# iOS - How to get date always at midnight?

Tags: ios, date

I am trying to get dates at midnight like, for example, `2019-08-01 00:00:00 +0000`.

I have googled and tried to use all the possible answers that I found. But for some wired reason that I don't understand, none of them works.

I have used this code and I expect it to return `2019-08-08 00:00:00 +0000`, it does `2019-08-08 22:00:00 +0000`.

```
   var calender = Calendar.current
   calender.timeZone = Timezone.current

   calender.startOfDay(for: Date()) // 2019-08-08 22:00:00 +0000
```

So what is the easiest way to find midnight date irrespective of the timezone? In other words, how to get midnight date according to the users timezone?

Comment: Most likely it *does **not*** `2019-08-08 22:00:00 +0000` *it does* `2019-08-07 22:00:00 +0000`. This is correct as your time zone is `+0200`. `2019-08-08 00:00:00 +0200` is exactly the same point in time as `2019-08-07 22:00:00 +0000`. Consider that `print` displays dates always in UTC

Comment: @vadian Actually it returns `2019-08-08 22:00:00 +0000`. I just tired it again

Comment: `2019-08-08 22:00:00 +0000` is `2019-08-09 00:00:00 +0200`. Assign the value to a label and it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: You may find [this article](http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.

The last portion of the date string (`+0000`) represents the time zone. `+0000` is [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which includes the UK and western Africa. In other words, at midnight in the user's current time zone, it is 22:00 in London, England.

If you want to format your date to display the time stamp in the user's current time zone, you will have to use `DateFormatter`.

I live in Chicago, USA (`-0500`), and I've adjusted my timestamps accordingly

```
var calender = Calendar.current
calender.timeZone = TimeZone.current

let midnight = calender.startOfDay(for: Date()) // 2019-08-09 05:00:00 +0000

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // Important!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatter.string(from: midnight) // 2019-08-09 00:00:00 -0500
```